# zend framework 2 view public function

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have read many entries and tried a lot (for example, viewhelpers), but unfortunately nothing works (which is definitely due to my little knowledge). We use the Zend Framework 2 internally with CdliTwoStageSignup (https://github.com/cdli/CdliTwoStageSignup). In this module i want to realize that you can only register if a specific date has not been exceeded. This is currently hardcoded, but should now work with a value from the sql database. This value is already used by other modules, but I do not get it in the module CdliTwoStageSignup. Otherwise, nothing is changed on the module. Unfortunately, I have little idea of php and Zend.

hardcoded looks like this: for submission_deadline a date is manually inserted at the moment

this is from module/CdliTwoStageSignup/view/email-verfication/form.phtml

```
<?php
if (time() < strtotime($this->submission_deadline)) {
        print '<h2>Step 1: <small>Email Verification</small></h2>';
    } else {
        print '<h2>Step 1: <small>Email Verification (disabled)</small></h2>';
    }
```

Because I have little idea of the framework, I searched in other modules and found that in a view/index.phtml:

```
<?php
//deadlines
    if($this->activeSemester){
        $submission_deadline = $this->activeSemester->getDtSubmissionDeadline();
    }
```

Can I use that?

This is a public function in /otherModule/Entity/otherModule.php

```
public function getDtSubmissionDeadline() {
        return $this->dtSubmissionDeadline;
    }
```

So in conclusion is my question: How can I use the variable in this module, what is my problem? I have tried solutions from similar issues, but unfortunately nothing worked. If anything is missing, I'll be happy to complete it.
Thank you very much for your help!